# Is this irrationality proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers, alternative-proof

Consider a non-square integer $n$. If its square root was rational, then we would have $$\sqrt n=\frac{a}{b}$$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and so $a^2=nb^2$. But this is impossible, because $n$ is non-square while $b^2$ *is* square, so that $nb^2$ cannot be equal to a square $a^2$. Therefore $\sqrt n$ is irrational whenever $n$ is a non-square integer.

I am just wondering because it seems like the standard "Pythagorean" proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational could be much simplified by just noting that $a^2=2b^2$ admits no integer solutions.

Comment: The statement "because $n$ is non-square while $b^2$ is square, so that $nb^2$ cannot be equal to a square $a^2$" is true, but it is not **clearly** true, so I would not consider this a proper proof.

Comment: Perhaps what makes it intuitively "obvious" is an implicit appeal to Unique Factorization. If we make that explicit, we do end up with a proof, but one that is longer and less elementary than the traditional argument.  That said, the argument is a good one, based on the multiplicative structure of the integers.

Comment: $3\cdot 2^2 = \sqrt{12}^2\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{12}],\,$ so a nonsquare times a square can be a square in some number systems. That this cannot occur in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ requires *rigorous* proof.

Comment: You should first reduce $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ to a simple fraction form, i.e., $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$.